# Chromosome related problems.

Tags: homework, chromosome, allele

1.) How many versions (alleles) of a gene can we carry if every chromosome is in pair?

2) What happens during the gamete formation (meiosis) ? Do the gene pairs stay together?

3) What happens then to the paternal and maternal sets of genes that we inherited ?

My attempts

1) I think that it could be any number, but confused with 2 as an answer.

2) Gene pairs must refer to homologous chromosome pairs which remain together in meiosis-I and get separated in meiosis-II. So in net process, it get separated.

3) It is used for producing proteins essential for body functioning by the process of transcription and translation. These genes with some changes (due to crossover) will also be transferred to second generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How many versions (alleles) of a gene can we carry if every chromosome is in pair?

The phrasing "if every chromosome is in pair" sounds a little bit funny. But it probably mean "or a diploid individual".

If an individual is diploid, then it has two copies of any given locus. If the term is new to you, a locus is a position in the genome (it may correspond to a gene or not). With two copies an individual can carry maximum two different copies, that is two alleles. The answer is `two`.

> What happens during the gamete formation (meiosis) ? Do the gene pairs stay together?

You nailed it!

> What happens then to the paternal and maternal sets of genes that we inherited ?

This is a slightly vague question IMO but I would suppose the main point that is being expected is a description of segregation and recombination (cross-over). You answer was good but I would suggest.

"The maternally and paternally inherited haplotype will recombine (cross-over) during meiosis so that a gamete resulting from meiosis will contain a single haplotype which is a 'mixture' of the maternally inherited and paternally inherited haplotypes."